# Script for missing Time card in Service Now

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I need to send a notification every Monday to all users located in a particular location along with their supervisor if they have missed filling time cards, or the time card state is pending.

I have tested the below script in the Background -Script section and for the users who don't have any entry in the time_card table for that week, are simple to find out. But for users who have more than one entry in a pending state, more than one notification will go out to them. I need a way to group that by state so only one notification is sent to a user per week that their time card is still pending.

```
var qry = 'active=true^location=7e294345ed9cf8c0b8536034d0f12dc7';
var Tqry = 'week_starts_onRELATIVEEE@dayofweek@ago@4';
var PuneUsr = new GlideRecord('sys_user');
PuneUsr.addEncodedQuery(qry);
PuneUsr.query();
gs.print("Pune Users: count" + PuneUsr.getRowCount());

while(PuneUsr.next()){
    var timecard = new GlideRecord('time_card');
    timecard.addQuery('user', PuneUsr.sys_id);
    timecard.addEncodedQuery(Tqry);
   timecard.query();
   if (timecard.getRowCount() == '0'){
   gs.print("row count" + timecard.getRowCount() + "user" + PuneUsr.sys_id.getDisplayValue());
   }
   if (timecard.getRowCount() != '0'){
       while (timecard.next()){
       gs.print("row count" + timecard.getRowCount() + "state" + timecard.getValue('state') + "user" + PuneUsr.sys_id.getDisplayValue() + "</br>" );
       }
   }
   }
```

I will add the event registry in place of the print statements and attach notifications to them. But as of now there are two statements printed for the 2nd gs.print if a user has two records in pending for the time card.

Not sure how to limit that so that only one event is created per user.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you're looking to generate only one event (or in the case of your test script up there, one gs.print()) PER USER.

Here is some code that would generate one event (gs.print() in this case) per user, but would include all of the details about each of their time cards (once you edit line 23):

```
//declare msg
var msg = '';
var qry = 'active=true^location=7e294345ed9cf8c0b8536034d0f12dc7';
var Tqry = 'week_starts_onRELATIVEEE@dayofweek@ago@4';
var PuneUsr = new GlideRecord('sys_user');
PuneUsr.addEncodedQuery(qry);
PuneUsr.query();
gs.print("Pune Users: count" + PuneUsr.getRowCount());

while(PuneUsr.next()){
    var timecard = new GlideRecord('time_card');
    timecard.addQuery('user', PuneUsr.sys_id);
    timecard.addEncodedQuery(Tqry);
    timecard.query();
    if (timecard.getRowCount() == '0'){
        gs.print("row count" + timecard.getRowCount() + "user" + PuneUsr.sys_id.getDisplayValue());
    }
    if (timecard.getRowCount() != '0'){
        //add header line only once for each user
        msg += 'You have ' + timecard.getRowCount() + 'timecard(s) pending:<br />'
        while (timecard.next()){
            //add a line to msg for each timecard that matches your query
            msg += 'put in some details about the timecard here, and maybe a link to it.<br />');
        }
        //print out the final result of msg for this user. 
        gs.print(msg);
    }
}
```

I added a comment above every line I added/modified so you can see which code is mine.

Here is another version which should spit out only one message per user, no matter how many timecards they have open:

```
var qry = 'active=true^location=7e294345ed9cf8c0b8536034d0f12dc7';
var Tqry = 'week_starts_onRELATIVEEE@dayofweek@ago@4';
var PuneUsr = new GlideRecord('sys_user');
PuneUsr.addEncodedQuery(qry);
PuneUsr.query();
gs.print("Pune Users: count" + PuneUsr.getRowCount());

while(PuneUsr.next()){
    var timecard = new GlideRecord('time_card');
    timecard.addQuery('user', PuneUsr.sys_id);
    timecard.addEncodedQuery(Tqry);
    timecard.query();
    if (timecard.getRowCount() == '0'){
        gs.print("row count" + timecard.getRowCount() + "user" + PuneUsr.sys_id.getDisplayValue());
    }
    if (timecard.getRowCount() != '0'){
        //change 'while' to 'if' so it only executes once, regardless of how many records are returned.
        if (timecard.next()){
            gs.print("row count" + timecard.getRowCount() + "state" + timecard.getValue('state') + "user" + PuneUsr.sys_id.getDisplayValue() + "</br>" );
        }
    }
}
```